# Does Chi-square distribution follow a Standard Normal distribution under Central Limit theorem? If yes, how do I prove it?

Tags: asymptotics, central-limit-theorem, moment-generating-functions, chi-squared

I tried using the Moment generating function technique..The Mgf is (1-2t)^(-n/2) for a chi-square distribution with n degrees of freedom..Now how do I proceed and converge this Mgf to that of a N (0,1) distribution?
Thanks.

Comment: Does it satisfy the conditions of the CLT?

Comment: Yes I guess....If i'm missing out something please mention it..

Comment: Then the answer is simple, right? You have to check the conditions and you have proved that the claim is true, namely under the CLT it will follow a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Yes I tried it via Moment generating function process but I'm getting stuck somewhere..I cant prove it atlast..please help

Comment: So you want to prove it manually,  or better formulated: without using the CLT itself?

Comment: Yes Sir...It would be of great help..I am totally confused.

Comment: Do you know the proof of the CLT? Then I would suggest that you follow the same proof for this particular case. I do not know how one can do it in another way.. I hope this helps.

Comment: No not actually..okk i shall try searching for the proof..

Comment: You give the mgf for an uncentered un scaled (raw, if you will) chi squared rv.  The next step on your chosen path is to write the mgf for the centered & scaled chi squared rv.  Your goal is to achieve pointwise convergence of your mgf to that of the standard normal.

Comment: Okay..Thanks..But I have less knowledge about centred chi square..